# Java For statements and scanner input

Tags: java, list, for-loop, input

```
        System.out.println ("Did you see that?");
        String response = input2.nextLine();
        System.out.println ("You said "+ response);     

        String[] responses = {"no", "NO", "No", "I did not"};

        List<String> response1 = Arrays.asList (responses);

        for (String response : response1  ){
            System.out.println ("That was weird");
        }
```

I'm new to java and was wondering how I could use a "for" statement in a way that, when you input one of the list of words such as "no", "NO", or "No", there will be a certain response that covers those inputs. I'm just looking to reduce the amount of if and else statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code is that you are using the same variable - `response` - for both the user input and the loop variable. Change the loop variable :

```
    for (String noResponse : responses  ){
        if (response.equals(noResponse)) { // you can also use .contains if you 
                                           // don't require an exact match
            System.out.println("You said no");
            break;
        }
    }
```

BTW, there's no need to convert the `responses` array to a `List`. The loop can iterate over the array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `contains()` method of list to check if it contains the response.Like this:

```
   System.out.println ("Did you see that?");
   Scanner input2=new Scanner(System.in);
    String response = input2.nextLine();
    System.out.println ("You said "+ response);     

    String[] responses = {"no", "NO", "No", "I did not"};

    List<String> response1 = Arrays.asList (responses);

    if(response1.contains(response)){
        System.out.println ("That was weird");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As an extra note, instead of making an array of possible responses you probably want to do something similar to this:

```
if(response.equalsIgnoreCase("no") || response.equalsIgnoreCase("I did not")){
     System.out.println("that was weird");
}
```

This will check for "no" or "I did not" but ignore the case so you don't have to worry about that.